# What do you call it when somone traps you with a question?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

Say I am disgusted by you eating chicken because I am a serious vegan. Instead of directly confronting you about it, I would approach you with a question like "awww...isn't this rabbit cute" while showing you a Snapchat of a rabbit. I'd deliberately prepared the clip so I could get you to agree.

Unsuspecting to my intention, you agree and say "awww...thats so cute"

Getting you to where I want, I pounce on you with "but you eat animals"

Thus leading you into a trap.

What do you call this leading into a trap?

Like, if there was a third person (an observant) in this situation and this person could see the my intention...they would warm the non-vegan by saying "be careful it's a ________" or, "be careful s/he is _________ing (you)"

Or if the person caught on to me and asked "what is the intention behind your question?" when presented with the "awww...isnt this rabbit cute?", the third person would say "it's a _____________"

Obviously, "trap" would fill the blanks nicely but it's NOT the word or phrase I'm looking for. I want I more precise word or phrase for this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “Rabbits aren’t cute, they are animals. Grow up!” is my suggestion for a response. But really, your problems with vegan friends are not the concern of this list.

Comment: This question seems far better suited to our site for [interpersonal.se]. Make sure to read their [guidelines for asking questions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: @tchrist This is asking about what term can be used that fits the definition, not how to approach the situation.

Comment: In terms of debate, I see no trap in the scenario. I can easily acknowledge that rabbits are cute while still eating animals—and possibly even rabbits. It's only a trap if the non-vegetarian thinks it's a valid argument against them. Or if some actual fallacy has been exposed. But if you want to consider it as some kind of underhanded emotional ploy, I suppose you could. (Note that an appeal to emotion is, itself, a logical fallacy. A reasonable debater would think that the person actually trapped themself by employing such a technique.)

Comment: It's a [*loaded question*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261148/whats-the-term-for-fallaciously-including-an-assumption-in-a-question) even if the fallacious assumption is implicit.  The fallacious assumption here being that anyone who thinks critters are cute couldn't eat critters.

Answer (score 2):

I think these best fall under the category of "leading questions"
That being said, I don't think there is a word for leading questions with the intent of tricking someone, though "gotcha question" seems to fit your examples well.

[leading question:](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/leading_question)
 A question that prompts or encourages the answer wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a "gotcha question" could fit here. Journalists will use them (or get accused of using them).

gotcha question - definition and synonyms
noun informal

a question designed to trip someone up

I’m not going to give you any gotcha questions.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gotcha-question