# Word for a type of question that's founded on a misunderstanding of a concept?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose someone asks the question:

> How long ago did humans evolve from monkeys?

Since humans did not evolve from monkeys, this question is unanswerable as it is based on a misunderstanding of the concept of human evolution.

Is there a technical word for these types of questions founded in a misunderstanding of a concept?  As in you would respond to this by saying:

> I cannot answer that because you've asked me a _______ question.

Comment: You've asked me a 'When did you stop beating your wife?' question.

Comment: _a nonsensical question_

Comment: a "stupid" question, air quotes *de rigueur*. That question is not based on a misunderstanding, it is based on lack of knowledge....

Comment: I will update the question to more clearly reflect what I am asking.

Comment: **Loaded**. Does this answer your question? [What's the term for fallaciously including an assumption in a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261148/whats-the-term-for-fallaciously-including-an-assumption-in-a-question)

Comment: That's called a "loaded question," so I'm agreeing with @WeatherVane. A loaded question is a question that's loaded with an assertion or assumption presented as fact that's actually false, unfounded, disputed, controversial, and/or a matter of opinion, which a question based on a misunderstanding of a concept would fall into. Loaded questions are unanswerable as written without implicitly conceding to the loaded assumption or assertion therein, which is at times the true purpose, not to ask a question but use the question as a trick to get the loaded element conceded to or agreed to as fact.